# Arquillian: Adding beans.xml causes "ArquillianServletRunner not found"

Tags: glassfish, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian[1] for testing my J2EE-App in an embedded glassfish environment inside Eclipse[2]-IDE.

```
package test.java;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchivePaths;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE,
            ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertNull(null);
    }
}
```

The test executes fine until I add the showed instruction ".addAsWebInfResource(...)". When doing this, following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI(ServletUtil.java:64)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletURIHandler.locateTestServlet(ServletURIHandler.java:60)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:77)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:263)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:226)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Without beans.xml, of course, CDI does not work.

How can I avoid this exception?

I have uploaded my pom.xml to http://pastxt.com/P/7IT1VYWBUW

Environment: jdk1.7.0_02 / Win7 / Eclipse Juno SR1

[1] https://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html

[2] http://www.eclipse.org/

Comment: Do you have a reproducible test case that I could work on ? While your test looks similar to [this particular one in the GF adapter](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-glassfish/blob/master/glassfish-embedded-3.1/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/glassfish/embedded_3_1/app/IntegrationWarTestCase.java), I'm unable to reproduce the failure that you see.

Comment: I have updated the question - the testclass is minimized without dependencies now, my pom.xml is available online; error exists on my side in this environment.

Comment: I saw this error several times on different projects and most of the time it was caused by the jar/war/ear setup in the @ Deployment annotated method. Check all dependencies and all classes you need for your test. Especially if you use EJB, drill down in the second or third level dependencies that are used as @ EJB reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've taken a look at your POM and your test. The issue appears to be related to [GLASSFISH-16964](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16964), going by the following log entries:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.10 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Dec 07, 2012 2:09:59 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
Dec 07, 2012 2:09:59 PM org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand execute
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

You have a few dependencies in your project that pull in v1.6.1 of `slf4j-api`. That appears to conflict with what embedded GlassFish requires - I believe it is `1.5.10` going by the logs of embedded GlassFish.

To resolve this particular issue, downgrade to the version that keeps GlassFish happy. I added the lower version as a managed dependency.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      ....
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.10</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencies>
```

Of course, this might have an impact on the other libraries that depend on the newer version of slf4-api, so you'll have to watch out for other issues.

The best way to resolve this would be to use the remote or managed GlassFish Arquillian adapter.

Comment: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Thank you!

Comment: dependency:tree is your friend!

Comment: i have the same problem and i tried the same solution given above but i have the same issue if i lets 
`JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)` or `JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"test.jar")`

But when i do like this : `JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"test")` it works good but when i try to inject any bean or ejb it doesn't work.


Any idea?

Comment: I have the same issue. Downgrading slf4j library does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.` seems to indicate that an error occured during the deployment. The message - you can think and express about what you want - has nothing to do with that error (source: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/173340)! **You need to access the logs to figure out what's wrong** which are either on the console or at a location which is configured in a file which is specified in the system property `java.util.logging.config.file`, e.g. add

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$s: %5$s%n
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
```

In my case it was missing `com.google.guava:guava:23.0:test` and the issue was unrelated to adding `beans.xml` as `Asset.EMPTY` of Shrinkwrap.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below to the web.xml did the trick for me :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ArquillianServletRunner</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ArquillianServletRunner</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ArquillianServletRunner</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Glassfish embedded 3.1.2. But it seems to be fixed in 3.1.2.2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```