# ArquillianServletRunner not found

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

I've got yet another non-working Arquillian test:

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SomeTest {

private static final String APPLICATION_XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
        + "<application xmlns=\"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd\" version=\"6\">"
        + "<display-name>org.acme.project</display-name></application>";

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class);
    ear.setApplicationXML(new StringAsset(APPLICATION_XML));
    ear.addAsModules(Testable.archiveToTest(ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)));
    return ear;
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("SomeTest.test()");
}

}
```

This class is all it takes for the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI(ServletUtil.java:64)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletURIHandler.locateTestServlet(ServletURIHandler.java:60)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:84)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
....
```

I've seen other questions around (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750005/arquillian-adding-beans-xml-causes-arquillianservletrunner-not-found)), but all of them seem to be using Glassfish, whereas I use a managed Wildfly 8.1.

Nonetheless, since slf4j has crept its way into my dependency list, I tried different versions of it (1.5.10, 1.6.6, 1.7.13).

As always with this things, there is no indication in the server log (or anywhere) that something went wrong, only the JUnit runner (of Eclipse and Maven) complains. Tests with other deployments run fine.

What's wrong?

Comment: This message seems to indicate that an error occurred during deployment which has nothing to do with the message. I posted an answer to the referenced question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750005/arquillian-adding-beans-xml-causes-arquillianservletrunner-not-found/46615704#46615704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone with the same problem. This is how it works (see the comments for the changes):

```java
private static final String APPLICATION_XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
        + "<application xmlns=\"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd\" version=\"6\">"            + "<display-name>org.acme.project</display-name>"
        // the WAR must be added to the application.xml !
        + "<module><web><web-uri>test.war</web-uri><context-root>/test</context-root></web></module>"
        + "</application>";

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class);
    ear.setApplicationXML(new StringAsset(APPLICATION_XML));

    // to add the WAR to the application.xml, it must have a name
    WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
    // the test class must be added manually for whatever reason
    webArchive.addClass(SomeTest.class);
    ear.addAsModules(Testable.archiveToTest(webArchive));
    return ear;
}
```